# Selected item in navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I implemented the navigation drawer in my app (http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

How can I change the display of the actually selected item? I want the selected item to be bold and a different color.

In the official example, they use "setItemChecked", but how can I modify the aspect of the single checked item? The "setOnItemSelectedListener" method doesn't work.

So far, what I do is this piece of code when I open a fragment:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mDrawerList.getChildCount(); i++){
    TextView t = (TextView) mDrawerList.getChildAt(i);

    if(i == fragmentPosition) t.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
    else t.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
}
```

It works, but on app launch, no item is selected, and I can't set any item because the listview isn't created yet (it's created when we open it the first time, I think).

I tried creating a selector, but don't know how to set the different attributes correctly (item checked, item selected, item clicked??), searched the docs but I don't understand.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 4):

I would do it in adapter.

```
mAdapter.setSelectedItem(position);

public View getView(...) {
    ...
    if (position == mSelectedItem) {
        text.setTypeface(...);
        text.setBackgroundColor(...);
    } else {
        text.setTypeface(...);
        text.setBackgroundColor(...);
    }
}
```

And if you don't need to set typeface you can use selector with

```
setTextColor(@drawable/my_selector).
```

Or put it to your xml file with TextView

```
android:textColor="@drawable/my_selector"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution to change the color and typeface of the selected item in the navigation drawer...

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
     setNavDrawerItemNormal();
     TextView txtview = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNav));
     txtview.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
     txtview.setTextColor(R.color.Red);
}

public void setNavDrawerItemNormal()
{
    for (int i=0; i< mDrawerListView.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        View v = mDrawerListView.getChildAt(i);
        TextView txtview = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtNav));
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
        txtview.setTypeface(font);
        txtview.setTextColor(R.color.Red);
    }
}
```

And to bold the first item in the navigation drawer upon initialization of the app, I did that in the list adapter get view method...

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navdrawer_item, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtNav);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
    if (position == 0) 
    { 
       textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
       textView.setTextColor(R.color.Red);
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

So, in here i checked if the position of the item is 0 (meaning its the first item), then make it bold. This whole thing works perfectly for me!~

Comment: It's a dirty hack! It misleads people. Use `CheckedTextView`instead! Also use `myDrawerListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)`.